# How to integrate the function $\ f(x)=\arctan(\sqrt{\sqrt{x}-1}) $

Tags: calculus, integration

How to integrate the function $\ f(x)=\arctan(\sqrt{\sqrt{x}-1}) $

I tried by $\ u=\arctan(\sqrt{\sqrt{x}-1}) $ and $\ dv=dx $, but wolfram alpha doesn't agree.

My solution is $\arctan(\sqrt{\sqrt{x}-1}) \cdot x -\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{2}\ln(\sqrt{x}-1)$

Comment: I cannot see a logarithm coming integrating by parts (which is a good idea).

Comment: i get $\ du=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x}-1}*\frac{1}{2(\sqrt{x}-1})*\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$

Answer (score 2):

Integrate by parts:

$\int f \: \text{dg} = fg -\int g \: \text{df} $

where

$f = \arctan(\sqrt{\sqrt{x}-1})$

$\text{dg} = \text{dx}$

$\text{df} = \frac{1}{4x \sqrt{\sqrt{x}-1}} \text{dx}$

$g=x$

This gives

$$\int \arctan(\sqrt{\sqrt{x}-1})\: \text{dx} = x \arctan(\sqrt{\sqrt{x}-1})
- \int \frac{1}{4x \sqrt{\sqrt{x}-1}}\: \text{dx}$$

Focusing on the remaining integral, substitute $u = \sqrt{x}$.

$$
- \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{u}{\sqrt{u-1}} \: \text{du}$$

substitute $s = u-1$

$$
- \frac{1}{2} \int \sqrt{s} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}} \: \text{ds}$$

Now it should be straight forward to finish.